# Xamarin.Forms multiple WebViews but OnPageFinished only seems to apply to last Webview?

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android

I have a ListView with three seperate WebViews inside of it. Each Webview has it's own HTML content. These Webviews need to be responsive (the height should adjust to the content it loads).

Since these webviews differ in height, I am using Javascript to calculate the height. For some reason this does NOT work when using multiple webviews. It seems to only work on the last one.

I am not sure what is happening - it seems to fire the OnPageFinished event multiple times but the heightrequest is mostly ignored. It even happens without Javascript (so if i hardcode a set value for the heightrequest instead)

Here is the code for the WebView:

```
 public class HybridWebViewLeft : WebView
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty messageContentProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create(nameof(messageContent), typeof(string), typeof(HybridWebViewLeft), string.Empty);
        public string messageContent
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(messageContentProperty).ToString(); }
            set { SetValue(messageContentProperty, value); }
        }



        public HybridWebViewLeft()
        {

            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            Margin = 0;
            HeightRequest = 10;        
            Source = "";

            this.PropertyChanged += HybridWebViewLeft_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void HybridWebViewLeft_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(messageContent)))
            {

                var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
                htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
                                    <head>
                                    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>
                                    <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""chatmessage-content.css"">
                                    </head>
                                    <body style=""background-color: #DDDDDD;"">Test1<br>Test2<br>Test3<br>Test4<br>Test5<br>Test6<br>Test7<br>Test8 " + 
                                    "<script>function setresponseandsubmit(content) { console.log(content); CSharp.setresponseandsubmit(content); }</script></body></html>";

                htmlSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
                Source = htmlSource;

            }

        }
```

And here is the code on Android:

```
       class HybridWebViewLeftClient : WebViewClient
        {
            WebView _webView;

            public async override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
            {

                try
                {
                    _webView = view;
                    if (_xwebView != null)
                    {
                        view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                        view.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                        await Task.Delay(100);


                        string result = await _xwebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()");
                        _xwebView.HeightRequest = Convert.ToDouble(result);

                    }
                    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"EXCEPTION: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
```

_xwebView.HeightRequest is correctly calculated for the last WebView, the other two come back as null so the initial height of 10 is used.

Comment: Did you put three webviews in the same cell ? It would be better if you can post the full code in xaml and code behind .

Comment: No they are in seperate cells. Even if I stack the WebViews the problem still remains

Comment: Could you share a sample so that I can test it on my side . Your code couldn't let mt to reproduce the issue .

Comment: I can do that - what would be the best way to do that? Via github? 
Sorry, still fairly new to this ;)

Comment: Post the sample to github .

Comment: https://github.com/SlimboTimbo/MultiWebviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**

In your sample you put the **WebViews** in a **StackLayout** . However , **StackLayout** will not fit its child elements in runtime . You need to set the height in advance .

**Solution:**

You should use **Grid** . And don't forget to set the `Scroll Orientation` of ScrollView .

```
 <ScrollView Orientation="Both">
    <Grid>


        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />


        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Testing multi webviews" BackgroundColor="Pink" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" />

        <custom:HybridWebView  Grid.Row="0" messageContent="1" />
        <custom:HybridWebView  Grid.Row="1" messageContent="2" />
        <custom:HybridWebView  Grid.Row="2" messageContent="3" />
        <custom:HybridWebView  Grid.Row="3" messageContent="4" />
        <custom:HybridWebView  Grid.Row="4" messageContent="5" />
        <custom:HybridWebView  Grid.Row="5" messageContent="6" />

    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

In addition, in you case if you want to put multiple WebViews in the same page . It would be better to use ListView with **DataTemplate** .

[image]

Comment: Putting the content in a grid (with Scroll Orientation) still seems to do the same thing: the height is only calculated on the last webview. Am i missing something?

Comment: Remove the line  HeightRequest = 20; in  `public HybridWebView()`

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thank you so much!

I find it strange how it did work on the last one as i would expect it would give the same problem on all webviews. 

Again, thank you so much for the time and effort you put into this, i really appreciate it!